# How to fetch the linked names?

Tags: php, mysql

I have fetched the data from two different tables is this.
But now, I want the following result with their original names and not the numbers like status 1 is for Good, and user_id=1 means "Mike".

[image: Urgent ?]

Comment: So just join your result again with the tables for users and status.

Comment: How can I join the already joined result?
It's not a table. It is result after the joining.

Comment: You should provide more details of your table structure, if you want us to help. Furthermore you should provide the query leading to the result above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `JOIN` your tables, something like:

```
SELECT f.FollowDate, s.StatusName, u.UserName
FROM Folowers f
INNER JOIN Users u    ON f.UserId = u.ID
INNER JOIN Statuses s ON f.StatusID = s.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

To select usernames using userID try using an [inner join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

And/or you can say 1 = good like so:

```
if($status == 1)
{
    echo "Good";
}
```

(though this can also be done with the inner join, if you have the values in another table ofcourse)

Comment: I have already used join.
and tbl_status is a separate table.

I used join command as,
SELECT tbl_customer_conversation.follow_date, tbl_customer_conversation.status, tbl_customer_conversation.user_id
FROM tbl_customer_conversation
INNER JOIN tbl_lms_user
ON tbl_customer_conversation.user_id=tbl_lms_user.user_id
where tbl_customer_conversation.follow_date= DATE(NOW()) AND tbl_lms_user.first_name = 'Be'

Comment: Ok... So does that work? I don't get the reason for the comment?

Comment: I mean my current command is what I wrote above.
How can I get the data by modifying my same statement.